# How to structure my config.php file to use within classes in other files

Tags: php, configuration-files

I have some variables and constants in a config file that I want to use in a method of a class in another both `config.php` and `myclass.php`are in the same folder.

`config.php`

```
<?php
$a=1;
```

`myclass.php`

```
class MyClass
{
  protected function a () {
   include_once('config.php');
   echo $a; //$a is undefined here 
  }
}
```

Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: you can also return a variable (an array maybe?) from an included file. See example #5 in manual about `include`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another class in your config file and it will serve as a wrapper for all your config values and operations. This is the best approach also if you are giving value to OOP in your project development.

`config.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * PhpDoc...
 */
class YourConfig
{
  /**
   * Your constant value
   */
  const DB_HOST = 'localhost';

  /**
   * @var string Some description
   */
  private $layout = 'fluid';

  /**
   * Your method description
   * @return string layout property value
   */
  public function getLayout()
  {
    return $this->layout;
  }
}
```

`myclass.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * PhpDoc
 */
class MyClass
{
  private $config;

  public function __construct()
  {
    require_once( __DIR__ . '/config.php' );
    $this->config = new Config();
  }

  protected function a()
  {
    // get a config
    echo $this->config->getLayout();
  }
}
```

You can use and extend this approach for what/however you want.

Comment: looks very clean .Thanks